# Fibonacci number overflow in c++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am a `c++` newbie, and start learning it by learning algorithm at the same time. However, I encountered some problem when writing this algorithm --- the number overflows, which is quite different to the overflow I thought. To solve the problem, I searched for a long time, but end up in no use. Here is my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

long long Fs[101];
long long F(int N) {
    if (Fs[N] != -1) {
        return Fs[N];
    }
    int res = F(N - 1) + F(N - 2);
    Fs[N] = res;
    return res;
}

void main() {
    // initialize Fs array
    for (auto& item : Fs) {
        item = -1;
    }
    Fs[0] = 0;
    Fs[1] = 1;
    cout << F(60) << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (auto& item : Fs) {
        cout << item << endl;
    }
}
```

Part of the result is shown here:

```
165580141
267914296
433494437
701408733
1134903170
1836311903
-1323752223
512559680
-811192543
```

**Question**:
You can see that the overflow number is quite small than the minimum value of `long long` type.  Why this happened?

---

**Appendix**
I found some way to print the overflow index of unsigned type when generating `fibonacci`, here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
 
#define outFibonacci(nType) { int i = 1;\
    while (i++)\
        if (Fibonacci<nType>(i+1)==Fibonacci<nType>(i+2)){\
            cout<<"F("<<i<<")\t= "<<Fibonacci<nType>(i)<<endl;\
            break;\
        }\
    cout<< "Max Num\t= " << numeric_limits<nType>::max() << endl << endl;\
    }
 
template<typename _T> _T Fibonacci(_T n){
    _T f, f1, f2;
    f = f1 = f2 = 1;
    for (auto i=3; i<=n; ++i){
        f = f1 + f2;
        if (f<f2){ // Set overflow condition
            f=-1;
            break;
        }
        f1 = f2;
        f2 = f;
    }
    return f;
}
 
int main(void)
{   
    outFibonacci(unsigned short);
    
    outFibonacci(unsigned int);
    outFibonacci(unsigned long);
    
    outFibonacci(unsigned long long);
    outFibonacci(size_t);
    
    return 0;
}
```

and here is my result:

```
F(24)   = 46368
Max Num = 65535

F(47)   = 2971215073
Max Num = 4294967295

F(47)   = 2971215073
Max Num = 4294967295

F(93)   = 12200160415121876738
Max Num = 18446744073709551615

F(93)   = 12200160415121876738
Max Num = 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: Look at the type here: `int res =...` If only you hadn't introduced that variable... (`return Fs[N] = F(N - 1) + F(N - 2);`)

Comment: Why this happened? Because `res` is of `int` type. Change it to `long long`.

Comment: Suggestion: Learn about _debugging_. It would reveal quickly where the problem was.

Comment: Just as a side note: `f = f1 + f2; if (f<f2)` is only valid for unsigned, undefined behaviour for signed. Sure, you only *did* apply to unsigned, but keep in mind ;)

Comment: About [`using namespace std`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)...

Comment: You should use `uintmax_t` instead of `long long`: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in your function **int res = F(N - 1) + F(N - 2);** makes your result an int, which is then casted to long long. so the overflow occurs here. Should be flagged by some compilers flags tho.

```
long long F(int N) {
    if (Fs[N] != -1) {
        return Fs[N];
    }
    // int res = F(N - 1) + F(N - 2); // HERE !
    long long res = F(N - 1) + F(N - 2);
    Fs[N] = res;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: What a ..... How stupid am I.

Comment: I recommend using some flags with your compiler works on `g++` or `clang` :
https://interrupt.memfault.com/blog/best-and-worst-gcc-clang-compiler-flags#-wall---wextra
It may help you identify such things, I will always have at least `-Wall -Wextra`

Comment: @zarkli Not stupid – just unattendent ;)

Comment: Sometimes, you just have to stand up ; drink a coffee/tea/water walk 2 minutes and get back to the function